# Project Euler 22 - getting wrong numbers

Tags: python

I am new to Python and Machine Learning. I am trying to solve [Project Euler #22](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22) which needs to get alphabetical value from each name and multiply with its alphabetical position.
The correct answer is 871198282, however I keep getting 823763619.

I've checked the .txt file which contains names. They look OK and were imported the name file without any issue. I've checked the code step by step. When I call any name among the given names individually, my functions give me correct numbers, for instance, COLIN, it gives me 49714. 
Then I thought my main body is wrong where I combine all the numbers together, however for me it looks fine.

Can you please give me some clues where I have to look at carefully?
Additionally, I know my code looks like a noob, any suggestion I can make for my code to upgrade to the next level?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
# Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, 
# begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value 
# by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.

# For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, 
# is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.

# What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

total_counts = []

path ='C:\\python_practice_data'
file_path = os.path.join(path, 'name.txt')
name_list = pd.read_csv(file_path)
name_list=list(name_list)
name_list.sort()

def counts(name):
    _alphabet = {
        'A': 1,
        'B': 2,
        'C': 3,
        'D': 4,
        'E': 5,
        'F': 6,
        'G': 7,
        'H': 8,
        'I': 9,
        'J': 10,
        'K': 11,
        'L': 12,
        'M': 13,
        'N': 14,
        'O': 15,
        'P': 16,
        'Q': 17,
        'R': 18,
        'S': 19,
        'T': 20,
        'U': 21,
        'V': 22,
        'W': 23,
        'X': 24,
        'Y': 25,
        'Z': 26              
    }

    total = 0
    cha_name=[]

    for i in range(len(name_list)): 

        if name in name_list[i]:
            cha_name = list(name)
            print(cha_name)

            for j in range(len(cha_name)):
                if cha_name[j] in _alphabet:
                    total += _alphabet[cha_name[j]]
                    #print(total)
                else:
                    break

            return total
#Count the name in alphabericl order
def numbering(name):
    for i in range(len(name_list)):

        if name in name_list[i]:
            #print(i+1)
            break

        else: 
            continue

    return i+1    

#Main
for i in range(len(name_list)):
    name = name_list[i]
    total_numbers = numbering(name)*counts(name)
    total_counts.append(total_numbers)
    print(sum(total_counts))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit long and there's too much to unpack to cover everything here, but here's some notes.

Regarding your `counts` function:

- it appears the goal is to sum the total of character values for a name, with A=1, B=2, etc.; so 'Colin' (as 'COLIN') would be 53.
- you reference `name_list`, but you don't actually use it for anything other than checking if `name` is on the list, but that doesn't matter for what the function does.
- you have an elaborate enumeration of the alphabet, assigning a number to each letter, but there are standard functions that do this for you.

A far shorter version of your `count` function:

```py
def count(name):
    return sum([ord(ch)-64 for ch in name.upper()])
```

This computes the sum of the list of character values for all character in `name`. It calls `name.upper()` to ensure all letters in the name are converted to uppercase. It uses `ord(ch)` to get the ordinal value of each character - `ord('A')` is 65, `ord('B')` is 66, etc., so it subtracts 64 to get A=1, B=2, etc.

The rest of your code is supposed to:
- read the input file (supposedly with unique names, no duplicates)
- sort it alphabetically
- use the resulting list to compute for each name on the list its position on the list times its character value as computed with `count`
- sum the total for all names

Regarding your `numbering` function:

- it doesn't actually do anything, other than returning the total number of names in a really roundabout way
- what I think you intended it to do is to compute the position of a name in the list of names

Again, that only takes a single line:

```py
number = name_list.index(name)
```

Every list has a method that just tells you what the index of a value in the list is. So, if `'Colin'` is number 938 on the list, `name_list.index('COLIN')` would return 938.

Finally, you use `pandas` to read the file, but since you don't use `DataFrame` or any other `pandas`-specific data structure and only want everything in a list, you could just as easily use the built-in Python libraries - even more so since it's not really a .csv but just a flat text file with names.

The entire program then becomes something like:

```py
def count(name):
    return sum([ord(ch)-64 for ch in name.upper()])


with open('C:\\python_practice_data\\name.txt', 'r') as f:
    name_list = sorted(f.read().split())
    result = sum([count(name) * (name_list.index(name) + 1) for name in name_list])
    print(result)
```

Note: adding 1 to `name_list.index(name)` because `index` starts at 0, but the first name should probably be in position 1, not 0.

Or, if you don't like the shorthand of so-called list comprehensions:

```
def count(name):
    result = 0
    for ch in name.upper():
        result += ord(ch)-64
    return result


with open('C:\\python_practice_data\\name.txt', 'r') as f:
    name_list = sorted(f.read().split())
    result = 0
    for name in name_list:
        result += count(name) * (name_list.index(name) + 1)
    print(result)
```

Nothing really advanced is used here, no external libraries are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments. It helped a lot to review my code. I've just edited little bit on your suggested code as it also counts double quotes in count function. Thanks!